# Copying Filename From Origin Excel Workbook Into Destination Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to copy the filename from an opened Excel workbook, and paste it into a destination workbook? I have a macro that copies the data from my open workbook, but I'm not sure how to grab the filename.

This is the macro I have to copy the entire selection from my open workbook. How would I add the filename to this? Thank you!

```
Sub LazyBill()
' LazyBill Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
Dim SFC_Ver
Dim WB1 As Workbook, WbName As String
Dim WB2 As Workbook, Wb2Name As String
'Dim Ksearch As Range
Dim Kvalue As String
Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
    WbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'Open .cvs file to input
'MsgBox ("Once you click OK a File Open window will appear. Browse to the .cvs file that you wish to add to the trend data and click open")
    Filename = False
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
        If Filename = False Then
            CloseMaster
        End If
        
Dim sStarDir As String
sStarDir = CurDir
    ChDir "\\sw\data\****"
Application.DefaultFilePath = sStarDir

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    Filename
            Set WB2 = ActiveWorkbook
                Wb2Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(WbName).Activate
    Sheets("DATA").Select
'Paste data into trend data file
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
'Close Trend data .cvs file
    Windows(Wb2Name).Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Add it where?  To the same sheet as the pasted data?

Comment: Yes, all my copied data goes to a destination sheet, and I would like the origin of the data, as well as the filename of that data, to go to the same sheet.

Comment: Where exactly though?

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. I'd like to figure out how to copy the filename from the origin workbook, WB2. Then paste that filename to an open cell, A4, for example, in the destination workbook, WB1, in sheet "DATA". Don't know if it's possible and I've tried recording a few macros without success.

Comment: Wouldn't that get overwritten by the copied data from the source worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example - adjust the destination ranges to suit:

```vb
Sub LazyBill()

    Dim WB1 As Workbook
    Dim WB2 As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range, destWs As Worksheet, Filename
    
    Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'Open .cvs file to input  '.csv ?
    'MsgBox ("Once you click OK a File Open window will appear. " & _
      "Browse to the .cvs file that you wish to add to the trend data and click open")
    Filename = False
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If Filename = False Then
        CloseMaster
        'Exit Sub ' ?
    End If
        
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filename) 'set reference on file open
    Set rng = WB2.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    
    Set destWs = WB1.Worksheets("DATA")
    
    destWs.Range("A1").Value = WB2.Path
    destWs.Range("A2").Value = WB2.Name
    rng.Copy destWs.Range("A4")
    WB2.Close False
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Note you can work with workbook objects directly instead of referencing them by their name.

Comment: Thank you Tim, this works well. I hadn't figured to use objects directly and my code is very inelegant. Your solution is great for pasting the data and then the filename info so the filename or data isn't overwritten by the next set of data being entered. Thank you again